# extract strings from database's table

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have database's table containing source code (not a traditional language ) which i want to parse using regex ; I want to know, should I proceed row by row, or should I copy all of the rows to a text file to process them using regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on the length of the code. If the code is short then it's better to parse it in one time (read all rows). But if the code length is large then it's better to parse it chunk by chunk. Let's say 100 rows and after that another 100 rows and etc. I think It depends on parsing performance

Comment: i tried to copy the rows in one String but it seems  it s to long that can be puted in one string , so i'm thinking of coping it in a text file

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your question

Comment: Was my answer useful for you?

Comment: You didn't justify your response.

Comment: how can i read all rows , i'm using  while (rs.next()) {
      String name = rs.getString(2);
    
    } it read line by line

Comment: String name =""; while (rs.next()) {  name = name + rs.getString(2); }